# Install 32-bit library packages on 64-bit rhel 6.2 during installation of os

Tags: rhel, system-installation, kickstart

I want full installation of `rhel-server-6.2-x86_64`.
Within this setup, I want to install some of 32bit glibc packages before completion of installation, which already available in `rhel-server-6.2-x86_64-dvd`.

I select all optional packages during installation, but as I see [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/36238) redhat(anaconda) will not install 32bit libs. But it is supported in 5.x (I tried that in 5.5 & 5.7)? How to make this possible in 6.2 or 6.3? Is it possible to install packages from dvd by `kickstart`, if yes then how?

Comment: why is it crucial to install the 32bit libraries during the system installation? e.g. why can't you install them afterwards?

Comment: @umläute Our customer is not allow to install any addition packages after installation of os on h/w(spatially 32-bit),this was work fine on 5.x as mansion above.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify in the kickstart file that you want to install the 32-bit version of a package if running on a 64-bit machine.

> To install a 32-bit package on a 64-bit system, you will need to
>   append the package name with the 32-bit architecture the package was
>   built for.
>
> For example: glibc.i686

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-packageselection.html

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure a kickstart](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/ch-redhat-config-kickstart.html) with the GUI-based `system-config-kickstart` and specify that the installation must be done from the DVD or some other installation method.

If you want to install 32-bit libraries and `anaconda` can't do it (for some reason), you can make a `%post` section in the `%packages` definition, where you can install your 32-bit packages, and add more configuration options that you need. This section allows you to install them normally like if you were doing it from `bash`:

```
%post
yum install my32lib.i686
```